# Function for creating contingency table with two categorical variables in R

Tags: r, function, dataframe, crosstab

I am creating a crosstab with two categorical variable with below code:

```
library(dplyr)
library(reshape2)

T1.1<-table(data$Q7_1,data$Q9,exclude = NULL)
T1.1<-data.frame(T1.1)
T1.2<-dcast(T1.1, Var1~Var2)
T1.2<-T1.2%>%mutate(Industry=as.character(Var1),Total_responses=A+B+C)%>%select(Industry,A,B,C,Total_responses)
C<-c("Industry"="ALL", colSums(T1.2[,2:5]))
T1.2<-rbind(C,T1.2)
```

This gives output:

```
                     Industry  A  B  C Total_responses
1                         ALL 20 18 18              56
2  Banking/Financial Services  2  2  2               6
3                   Chemicals  0  1  2               3
4              Consumer Goods  1  1  1               3
5                      Energy  2  1  0               3
6                   High Tech  6  0  2               8
7       Insurance/Reinsurance  0  2  0               2
8               Life Sciences  0  0  0               0
9                   Logistics  0  0  2               2
10            Mining & Metals  1  1  1               3
11        Other Manufacturing  1  2  0               3
12    Other Non-Manufacturing  3  2  2               7
13         Retail & Wholesale  1  1  0               2
14   Services (Non-Financial)  2  4  5              11
15   Transportation Equipment  1  1  1               3
16                       <NA>  0  0  0               0
```

This output is ok, but the issue is after I use table() function , I convert it to data frame and then use dcast to get desired look of the table. After dcast it creates another column NA, that I don't want.

Also I want to use this entire calculation to make a function which I can use for other factors with more levels.

Q9 has 3 levels A,B and C, I don't want to calculate the Total Response like this, I want to create function that can be used with any other factor with different number of levels. Please suggest any other efficient ways.

```
> dput(data)
structure(list(Q7_1 = structure(c(5L, 5L, 14L, 1L, 9L, 13L, 1L, 
3L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 12L, 2L, 11L, 13L, 10L, 11L, 1L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 
4L, 5L, 9L, 2L, 4L, 13L, 10L, 13L, 13L, 11L, 1L, 11L, 5L, NA, 
1L, 9L, 3L, 1L, 5L, NA, 2L, NA, 6L, 14L, NA, NA, 14L, 8L, 11L, 
8L, 12L, 13L, NA, 3L, 11L, 11L, NA, 10L, 6L, 5L, 13L, 13L), .Label = c("Banking/Financial Services", 
"Chemicals", "Consumer Goods", "Energy", "High Tech", "Insurance/Reinsurance", 
"Life Sciences", "Logistics", "Mining & Metals", "Other Manufacturing", 
"Other Non-Manufacturing", "Retail & Wholesale", "Services (Non-Financial)", 
"Transportation Equipment"), class = "factor"), Q9 = structure(c(1L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, NA, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, NA, 2L, NA, 2L, 2L, NA, NA, 1L, 3L, 
1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, NA, 1L, 3L, 1L, NA, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L), .Label = c("A", 
"B", "C"), class = "factor")), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -63L),  .Names = c("Q7_1", 
"Q9"))
```

>

Comment: Could you possibly show what your current results are, what you get form the current code in you post and what your desired output is? Please also demonstrate how your current code falls short. It is not clear what you are asking? (also, you should delete `, .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x0000000000100788>,` from your `structure`, it will create problems for people who are not using your computer.

Comment: Also, please complete your code my adding all libraries you use.

Comment: I have edited the question, hope its better now

Answer (score 1):

To convert a table into a data frame we can use `as.data.frame.matrix()`.

```
crossCalc <- function(data){
  t <- table(data$Q7_1, data$Q9)
  t <- as.data.frame.matrix(t)
  Total_responses <- with(t, A + B + C)
  t <- cbind(t, Total_responses)
  t <- rbind(ALL=colSums(T1.1), T1.1)
  return(t)
  }

crossCalc(data)
#                             A  B  C Total_responses
# ALL                        20 18 18              56
# Banking/Financial Services  2  2  2               6
# Chemicals                   0  1  2               3
# Consumer Goods              1  1  1               3
# Energy                      2  1  0               3
# High Tech                   6  0  2               8
# Insurance/Reinsurance       0  2  0               2
# Life Sciences               0  0  0               0
# Logistics                   0  0  2               2
# Mining & Metals             1  1  1               3
# Other Manufacturing         1  2  0               3
# Other Non-Manufacturing     3  2  2               7
# Retail & Wholesale          1  1  0               2
# Services (Non-Financial)    2  4  5              11
# Transportation Equipment    1  1  1               3
```

Maybe this is what you want?